# Custom Build PC not restarting at all

Tags: boot, motherboard

I have finally finished building my first PC but am facing a issue that I cannot seem to get to the bottom.

The PC will not completely restart, It will:

- Boot up
- Boot into BIOS
- Boot from USB to install windows even

I have updated the bios using latest Asus ProArt drivers from their website using EZFlash.

I have attempted to install windows  a number of times, I can agree to Microsoft terms, select 64-bit pro, format the drive for windows...But the installation proccess needs to reboot the PC several times and that never succeds.

When windows installer attemps to restart PC, the monitor shows a no "signal received" message and goes of but the lights on the PC case are still on, fans are still turning, all led lights are on too until I turn of the PC by holding the power button.

Needless to say, I am saddened by this, I know next to nothing about diagnosing PC hardware, what can I do?
I have so far only tried to remove all memory stick but one, no luck there.

A few questions:

- Can I boot the PC and even install windows without the RTX 3090 being  installed?
- Can I boot the PC and even install windows without any ram memory sticks being  installed?

What is this probelm even called? What can I even do? Any help would be appreciated.

| Part | Name |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | 5950x |
| GPU | RTX 3090 |
| RAM (256 GB) | Corsair Vengeance RGB RT 256GB (8x32GB) DDR4 3600MHz C18 |
| SSDx1 | SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 2TB PCIe NVMe Gen 4 |
| PSU | Seasonic PRIME TX 1600 |
| Water Coolor | ARCTIC Liquid Freezer II 420 |
| Fans | Noctua NF-A12x25 x6 |
| Motherboard | Asus proart x570-creator wifi |
| Case | Fractal Design Meshify 2 XL |
| Misc1 | ASUS ThunderboltEX 4 expansion card |
| Misc2 | TP-LINK AX3000 Wi-Fi 6 Bluetooth 5.2 PCI Express Adapter |

Comment: If you knew nothing about diagnosing PC hardware, then you really should not have built your own. Standard question though, did you take anti-static precautions? If not then you could have zapped the mothboard, the cpu, the memory, the ssd, the gpu or any of the extras and any combination of them, Try downloading one of the various unix iso's and see if that will install correctly. Try a different video card.

Comment: Re-check your memory timing in BIOS.  If memory compatibility mode is available, try that.  To rule-out power issues, pull-out unnecessary case fans while you're testing -- with the case open.

Comment: RTX 3090 - how many ports does this have, might it be that the installation process has somehow switched over to use one that has no monitor attached? (I consider Windows be broken in this manner! Too much automation!) - i.e. TURN OFF computer, switch cable / port / display - try a boot.